# notify user by sending an email to user whose last-login is more than 1 day

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, singleemailmessage, scheduled-job

Here is my code, please check

```
global class LastLoginEmail implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<User> uds =[SELECT Id, LastLoginDate, Email FROM User where IsActive=True];
        EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where Name=:'Users_Please_login']; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        for(User u : uds){
            If( u.LastLoginDate<=System.today().addDays(-1)){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
                mail.setTargetObjectId('User ID'); 
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
                mail.setUseSignature(false); 
                mail.setBccSender(false); 
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
                mail.setTemplateId(et.id); 
            }
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing here.

Comment: i scheduled this class for everyday , but users are not getting an email, Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Have you checked your org's email deliverability settings? How about the Apex Jobs logs, any error indicated there? You should probably be checking this for _active_ users only, and calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` outside of your loop, but nothing seems obviously wrong to me.

Comment: Yes I did check the settings, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Main Problem

```
mail.setTargetObjectId('User ID');
```

This line should be the user's ID, not literally the text "User ID":

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
```

## Other Problems

### Unrestricted Query

Query only the records you need:

```
List<User> uds =[SELECT LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND LastLoginDate < YESTERDAY];
```

### Query In A Loop

```
EmailTemplate et = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Users_Please_login'];
```

This line should be *before* the `for` loop.

```
EmailTemplate et = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Users_Please_login']; 
for(User u : uds){
```

### Messaging In A Loop

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
for(User u : uds){
  ...
  mails.add(mail);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please check the code which I posted the updated one in Question column.

Comment: @Mallikk (a) you still have a problem with the query as outlined in my answer. (b) you still have Messaging.sendEmail inside a loop as outlined in my answer. (c) For your new error, double-check the name of the template.

Comment: @Mallikk Yes, I addressed this in my answer; please read the section "Main Problem".

Comment: Hi, i changed as per your instruction to u.Id, still it gave me same error, then I tried it with User.ID still giving me same error.

Comment: @Mallikk You've done something wrong then. The code in the answer is perfectly correct based on your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Points I have noted in your code are

1. You have not set `setToAddresses` with Messaging object
2. Query `Email` field of User object as well
3. Always add limit or filter in your SOQL
4. No need to add `:` in your email template query unless you are referring a variable in SOQL
5. Set the required attributes of `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm)
6. **Never invoke `sendemail` method inside for loop**

Try below code and check.

```
global class LastLoginEmailJObs implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails =  new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(User u : [SELECT Id, LastLoginDate, Email FROM User]) { //You can add filter for active users only
            If( u.LastLoginDate <= System.today().addDays(-1)){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
                mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { u.Email });
                mail.setTargetObjectId('User ID'); 
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support'); 
                mail.setUseSignature(false); 
                mail.setBccSender(false); 
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
                EmailTemplate et = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name = 'Users_Please_login']; 
                mail.setTemplateId(et.Id); 
                mails.add(mail);
           }
        }
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

Comment: (a) Do not use setToAddresses to email users; they use daily limits. setTargetObjectId is sufficient. (b) setTargetObjectId should be set to `u.Id`. (c) No need to query email field. (d) No need to add a limit here, but should include filter `WHERE IsActive=TRUE and LastLoginDate < YESTERDAY` (e) Do not use SOQL in a loop.